# 403 Forbidden Error Simple php

Tags: php, directory

*I transferred only index.php and could see the page with no error. It is definitely something with my code, but I am very new to php and not sure what the problem is*

I got this error initially and thought it was because I was labeling file directory incorrectly. I corrected that and was able to see everything I transferred over on Sunday night, but came back this morning to this 403 error message again.
Is it still a file directory issue? 
Or is it something I am missing in my php code?
Here is index.php

```
<?php
$WEB_ROOT = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
$APP_PATH = 'pagelets';

$pagelet =$_GET['pagelet'];
require ("$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/includes/language.inc.php");
require_once ("$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/includes/functions.inc.php");

# index.php
if (!isset($pagelet))  {
$pagelet = "index";
}

// Include the page header.
include ("$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/includes/header.inc.php");

// Begin page content
echo "<h1 id='mainhead'>" . constant(strtoupper($pagelet) . '_TITLE') . "    </h1>";
include ("$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/pagelets/$pagelet.inc.php");

// End page content
include ("$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/includes/footer.inc.php");  //  Include the footer

?>
```

[image: file directory1]

[image: directory2]

Comment: 403's are a tad difficult.  The server can get it but won't ... usually server configuration.  Check file permissions?

Comment: Thank you KKinsey. I am a student and my instructor took care of server configuration and gave me access. Therefore I assume there is something I am missing in my code.

Comment: Do you use an .htaccess? And the Error you got is from the server or from php? Do you get any kind of PHP-Errors?

Comment: Luca Jung - the error is from php. I am able to upload index.php file only with html code in the file and it shows up with no error message. I do not use .htaccess.

Comment: In which line is the error and did you turn on error_reporting?

Comment: Good advice from Luca ... to explain further, add "error_reporting(E_ALL);"   and "ini_set('display_errors',1);" at the top of the script and let us know if you receive some helpful feedback from the PHP parser.

Comment: Not an answer yet, but can you verify that your paths are correct? Run just the following code and see if it outputs what you expect:

<?php
$WEB_ROOT = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
$APP_PATH = 'pagelets';
echo "$WEB_ROOT/$APP_PATH/includes/language.inc.php";
?>

Comment: Errors: 
"Notice: Undefined index: pagelet in /home/student071/public_html/index.php on line 9" and 
"Warning: include(/home/student071/public_html/pagelets/pagelets/index.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/student071/public_html/index.php on line 23" and

"Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/student071/public_html/pagelets/pagelets/index.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/student071/public_html/index.php on line 23"

Comment: Sophia, what URL are you using to see the page in the browser? More specifically we'd want to know the query string. I think we found your problem.

Comment: This is the link http://student071.webdev.seminolestate.edu/